# reading a datetime column as stringType in pyspark and converting it to datetime giving null records

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading an API call which have date in datetime column in below format
**2016-07-27T11:34:33Z+0000**

Now I am creating a dataframe using defining custom schema

```
StructField("xyz",TimestampType(),True),  
StructField("abc",TimestampType(),True)
```

Dataframe is getting created but when I am calling action its giving error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 73040.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 73040.0 (TID 408627, 10.239.145.102, executor 12): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: &#39;TypeError: field xyz: TimestampType can not accept object &#39;2016-07-27T11:34:50Z+0000&#39; in type &lt;class &#39;str&#39;&gt;&#39;. Full traceback below:
```

Tried:
I have tried creating the dataframe using schema type as stringType for datetime column its working but when I am converting that to datetime its giving null values.

```
df_mod = df_mod.withColumn("xyz",df_mod['xyz'].cast(TimestampType()))
```

this is giving null values.

[data when using stringtype while creating dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84GIB.png)

Please help How I can create the dataframe with this format 2016-07-27T11:34:33Z+0000 having schema type to be timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to convert this string `2016-07-27T11:34:33Z+0000` to epoch time by [`unix_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) in order to cast it to `TimestamptType`. Tricky part is you have to pass a correct date format.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '2016-07-27T11:34:33Z+0000'),
], 's int, a string')
+---+-------------------------+
|s  |a                        |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |2016-07-27T11:34:33Z+0000|
+---+-------------------------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('a', F.unix_timestamp('a', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'Z").cast('timestamp'))
    .show()
)
+---+-------------------+
|  s|                  a|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2016-07-27 04:34:33|
+---+-------------------+
```